# adding UIImageView to UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a UIScrollView set up in IB. I am adding in a UIImageView to it in viewDidLoad method but it's not working. Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName]];
    [scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [scrollView setContentSize:[imageView frame].size];
    [imageView release];
}
```

I NSLog-ed imageView and it's not null. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

EDIT: The screen is just blank. There's nothing there.

Comment: Why not just add it in IB?  Any particular reason for doing it in code? Also when you say "not working" that's very non-descriptive.  Please give a little more info, like "it doesn't display", or "it's the wrong size", etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason why I am not adding it in IB is because the image depends on view controller, so it changes...
Also, its not working as in the screen is just plain blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your UIScrollView isn't hooked up. Is the outlet for scrollview valid? Log scrollView to verify.

Comment: Yes, it's hooked up, here's the NSLog: <UIScrollView: 0x55240e0; frame = (10 12; 300 96); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x55242b0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>